# How to set custom DOM ID for tree nodes in Dojo 1.4?

Tags: dojo

I have written an application using Dojo 1.3 in which I have used the Dijit Tree component.
I am loading the tree with JSON data specified in the store which is in turn used by the tree model.

In the 1.3 version the tree elements pick up the id directly from the JSON data. However in 1.4 the tree elements have their own id which is something like `dijit_treenode_4`. The id's that I have specified in JSON are unique and im not able to understand why these are not being used anymore.

Please help me understand how this functionality has changed and how I can override the automatic id generation.

Thanks in advance,
Fell

Answer (score 0):

I think this design decision is a nice improvement on separating the model and view. The identifiers in store data really shouldn't have any impact on the tree node's DOM element ID by default.

Of course, if you want this behavior, you can achieve it. Define your own tree node class that overrides the DOM element ID.

```
dojo.require('dijit.Tree');

dojo.declare('yourapp.TreeNode', [dijit._TreeNode], {
    // summary:
    //         Tree node with custom ID.
    postCreate: function(){
        // summary:
        //         Overrides the normal `postCreate()` method to set custom ID
        //         for node DOM element.
        this.inherited(arguments);
        var id = this.tree.model.store.getValue(this.item, 'id');
        this.domNode.id = id;
    }
});
```

Then subclass `dijit.Tree`, and override method `_createTreeNode()` to create your custom tree nodes.

```
dojo.declare('yourapp.Tree', [dijit.Tree], {
    _createTreeNode: function(args) {
        return new yourapp.TreeNode(args);
    }
});
```